# How to find the limit of $\frac{1- \sqrt{x}}{1-x}$ as $x\to 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{1- \sqrt{x}}{1-x}$$

If I plug in the $1$, it is undefined because there is a vertical asymptote. I cannot factor it either so that it will not be zero. Also, $0/0$ is undefined as well.

Comment: Hint: factor the expression $1-x = 1 - (\sqrt{x})^2$.

Comment: Multiply the following limit by by $\frac{1+ \sqrt{x}}{1+ \sqrt{x}}$ and see what happens.

Comment: so you multiply by the conjugate, ok

Comment: Amending Dave's comment $1-x = 1^2 - (\sqrt{x})^2$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

$$(1-x) = (1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$$

Comment: that would still make the denominator zero.

Comment: never mind I see

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=t^2$ therefore 
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}&=\lim\limits_{t\to 1}\frac{1-t}{1-t^2} \\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to 1}\frac{1-t}{(1-t)(1+t)}\\&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: I like this solution the most. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1- \sqrt{x}}{(1-x)} = \frac{1-\sqrt x}{(1 - \sqrt x)(1 + \sqrt x)} = \frac 1{1+\sqrt x}$$

Now find $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt x}$$

Comment: your "hint" is pretty much a complete answer...   8-)